# how to recognize to function with requireJS ? -- Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, requirejs

I tryied to the requireJS for cicular dependencies many many times. I know there are different ways for circular dependencies and I read Q/A in stackoverflow but I didn't. My code in  the below and I am getting following error. How to fix this error? I tried [this method](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) in here. thanks in advance.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: require(...).fullNameAll is not a function

main.js

```
    define(["require","Employee", "Company"], function (require, Employee, Company) {
   require("Company").fullNameAll();

    });
```

Employee.js

```
define(["require", "Company"], function(require, Company) {
    function Employee(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    Employee.prototype.fullName = function() {
        console.log("I'm here");
        require("Company").test();
    };

    return Employee;
});
```

Company.js:

```
define( ["require", "Employee"], function(require, Employee) {
    function Company(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    Company.prototype.test = function() {

    console.log("test");
    };

    Company.prototype.fullNameAll = function() {
        var Employee = require("Employee");
        Employee.fullName();

    };
    return Company;
});
```

Comment: correct, `Employee.fullName` is not a function, if you `var x = new Employee('a', 'b');` then you'll find that  `x.fullName();` is a function - basic prototypal coding

Comment: @JaromandaX when I try as you say in main.js, is happening but in company.js, isn't happening and I'm getting same error. I want to access Employee.js's function inside the Company.js for circular dependencies. How will I do?

Comment: all I know is Employee.fullName isn't a function - I haven't bothered with the rest of the question as I don't use requireJS so can't be any help with specifics on circular dependencies

Comment: @JaromandaX You're correct. The issue is not RequireJS or circular dependencies but basic JavaScript. (There's actually no circular dependency in this code.)

Comment: @Louis There are circular dependencies in my orginal code like "a" needs "b" and "b" needs "a". Firstly I want to learn [this-method](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular) and access from main.js fullName method via Company.js. But I didn't.

Comment: @hamdi The code you show *in your question* has no circular dependency: `main` requires `Employee` and `Company`. `Company` requires `require` and `Employee`. `Employee` requires *nothing*. No circular dependency.

Comment: @Louis I have edited, what about now?

Comment: @hamdi Ok, now there is a circular dependency but the problem you're facing is still not due to the circularity. Jaromanda X explained the issue already.

Comment: @Louis I solved the problem, See the solution in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the my problem with "exports".
The solution:

main.js

```
define(["exports", "Company"], function (exports, Company) {
    var x = new Company.Company("hamdi", "bayhan");
    x.fullNameAll();
});
```

Employee.js

```
define(["exports", "Company"], function(exports, Company) {
    function Employee(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    Employee.prototype.fullName = function() {
        console.log("I'm here");
        var c = new Company.Company("qwe","tyu");
        c.test();
    };

    exports.Employee =  Employee;
});
```

Company.js

```
define( ["exports", "Employee"], function(exports, Employee) {
    function Company(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    Company.prototype.test = function() {

        console.log("test");
    };

    Company.prototype.fullNameAll = function() {
        var e = new Employee.Employee("asd","dsa");
        e.fullName();

    };
    exports.Company = Company;
});
```